# JUMPING ON collapsible BUTTON using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Dears Greetings,,

I want to jump from Group 1 to Group 3 by clicking on Text on Group 1. ((similar to an anchor link) )
using HTML or JS.

I really hope I can find the solution. I attached the code below

many thanks & best regards

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body"> <a href="#JumpToGroup3">click here</a> 
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea .</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"> <b id="JumpToGroup3">JUMP HERE</b> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click listner for your "click here" link and open the third panel by clicking it using js:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

  document.querySelector(".jumpTo").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".collaps3").click();
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body"> <a class="jumpTo" href="#JumpToGroup3">click here</a> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea .</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collaps3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body third"> <b id="JumpToGroup3">JUMP HERE</b> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                        ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: If this helped please accept my anwer, it can help other developers facing the same problem